# if i give both Session config in DD and setMaxInactiveInterval in servelt, which timeout will reflect in the application?

Tags: session

I have added entry in web.xml as below,

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

and added the below code in my servlet,

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);
```

Can i override the session time out values  in web.xml by using a method setMaxInactiveInterval?

Comment: Code will win here. not the markup.

Comment: why it so? any specific reason?

Comment: Markup is set first. then you modify it via code. ( not before). so who wins ?

Comment: Thanks @RoyiNamir so  we can override it .

Answer (score 0):

Code will overwrite for that specific session and any number of time you reuse it. (Like the above comment says)

If you want to make sure the reuse you can also say

request.getSession(false);

After first invication